# Being given.... shorten as Given the money

Tags: word-usage

> **Being given** the money, she left.

This can be shorten as follows:

> **Given** the money, she left.

However would it be possible to shorten the following sentence?

> **Being told** he had sixty days left, he changed his priorities and quit his job.
>
> **Told** he had sixty days left, he changed his priorities and quit his job.

To me the last sentence doesn't sound good. However I wonder when it is possible to omit "Being" in those kind of sentences.

Comment: Your second example needs a comma, otherwise the meaning is different.

Comment: Doesn't sound what?

Comment: @user3169 Please tell me....if the meaning of each sentence in the second example is different....so is in the first, right?

Comment: The second version of the sentences may seem ambiguous: (Having) given the money (to someone)... and (Having) told (that) he had sixty days left..., whereas the first versions are OK.

Answer (score 1):

> **Being told** he had sixty days left, he changed his priorities and quit his job.
>
> **Told** he had sixty days left, he changed his priorities and quit his job.

These both mean roughly the same thing.

> **Being given** the money, she left.

means money was handed to her.

> **Given** the money, she left.

could mean the same thing, but possibly [*given*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/given) means:

> 3) specific or previously stated

for example:

> She inherited a lot of money. **Given** the money, she left her neglectful boyfriend.

Comment: _Inherited_ might not be the best verb for your last example, given its relationship to the verb _give._ I'm just sayin.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence without "Being" are correct. The phrases are past participle phrases and mean roughly

> He was told that he had 60 days left, and so he changed priorities and quit his job.

The participle phrase acts as a complement to "He". In general a participle phrase doesn't ever need "Being"